# Java Snippet Marker compiler error

Tags: java, wid, websphere-process-server

I get the types `Java Snippet Marker` and `BPEL Editor Problem Marker` in my Java workspace. Those projects have access to external jars and the correct runtime (Websphere Process Server) and I'm not sure what it's complaining and the solution.

[image: Error Description and Type of Error]

Answer (score 1):

Try a clean build, sometimes the auto build will not be proper and it'll cause these kinds of errors to show up. You can also check the projects properties to make sure it has the proper rumtime and libs attached to it